# Convert Complex Entity to DTO With ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dto, modelmapper

i'm working in a rest API using Spring boot.
when i wanted to return my entity from an End Point i realized that the Properties are different from what i need on my response so i tried to use Model Mapper to return a DTO.

My entity is like this:

```
public class RuleEntity {

private String ruleId;
private String bankDecision;
private String aggregatorFunctionType;
private String limitOperatorType;
private double limitRule;
private Integer windowMinutes;
private Integer layer;
private String expressionRule;
private String status;
private List<GroupingKeyName> groupingKeyNames;
private List<RuleFilter> ruleFilters;
```

}

And the DTO that i need Must Be Like this:

```
public class RuleDTO {

private String ruleId;
private String bankDecision;
private String aggregatorFunctionType;
private String limitOperatorType;
private double limitRule;
private Integer windowMinutes;
private Integer layer;
private String expressionRule;
private String status;
private List<String> groupingKeyNames;
private List<String> ruleFilters;
```

}

The only change is that the last two lists are of String instead of The Object

The Objects groupingKeyNames and ruleFilters have a Name and an ID, and i only need the name on the list of DTO so it is a List of Strings

I tried using Model Mapper like this:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    RuleSetModel ruleSetModel =  modelMapper.map(ruleSetEntity, RuleSetModel.class);
```

it works, with all the properties but in the Lists it is returning something like:

```
groupingKeyNames=[GroupingKeyName(groupingKeyId=1, name=cardHash)], ruleFilters=[RuleFilter(ruleFilterId=1, name=status)]
```

What could i do so i get a result like this:

```
groupingKeyNames=[cardHash], ruleFilters=[status]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into ModelMapper Converters, see http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#converters and http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a method into your RuleEntity to do it**

```
    public RuleDTO dto() {
    // config to skip 
    PropertyMap<RuleEntity, RuleDTO> propertyMap = new PropertyMap<RuleEntity, RuleDTO>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            skip(destination.getGroupingKeyNames());
            skip(destination.getRuleFilters());
        }
    };

    RuleDTO ruleDTO = new RuleDTO();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
    modelMapper.addMappings(propertyMap);
    modelMapper.map(this,ruleDTO);

    if (!this.groupingKeyNames.isEmpty()) {
        ruleDTO.getGroupingKeyNames().clear();
        List<String> tmpGroupingKeyNames = new ArrayList<>();
        this.getGroupingKeyNames().forEach(itemDTO -> {
            tmpGroupingKeyNames.add(itemDTO.name);
        });
        ruleDTO.getGroupingKeyNames().addAll(tmpGroupingKeyNames);
    }

    if (!this.ruleFilters.isEmpty()) {
        ruleDTO.getRuleFilters().clear();
        List<String> tmpRuleFilters = new ArrayList<>();
        this.getRuleFilters().forEach(itemDTO -> {
            tmpRuleFilters.add(itemDTO.name);
        });
        ruleDTO.getRuleFilters().addAll(tmpRuleFilters);
    }
    return ruleDTO;
}
```